# How to cross-compile ARM version of LKM?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, kernel-module, netfilter

I need to perform MITM attack on a router, which is embedded linux system and its architecture is ARM.  The linux kernel is 2.4.24.  By MITM attack I mean intercept the packet, reedit it and send it forward.  I want to use netfilter. But when I try to cross compile the LKM, I encountered plenty of problems.

As usual, a LKM Makefile is as below:

```sh
obj-m+=hello.o
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

I downloaded linux kernel 2.4.24. But when it comes to the cross compile environment, the problems arise.

How to set `KDIR` path? The Path where `linux_kernel_2.4.24.tar.gz` is extracted? Do I need to cross-compile the kernel first? How?

Firstly, I set `KDIR` to the path of `linux_kernel_2.4.24`, then `make`, the error is "The present kernel configuration has modules disabled". By now I have not successfully `make menuconfig` this verion of kernel.

Secondly, I try to cross-compile on CentOS 5.4 32bit, whose kernel is 2.6.18.  When I add `CC=arm-linux-gcc` to `Makefile` and set KDIR as  `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`, the result says "there is no arm...".

Can anyone specify how to compile LKM of the old version kernel on the latest linux? And how to cross-compile ARM version of LKM?

Answer (score 1):

> How to set `KDIR` path? The Path where `linux_kernel_2.4.24.tar.gz` is extracted?

Yes, just as you normally would for any other kind of module, `KDIR` needs to point to the ***built*** kernel source root.

> Do I need to cross-compile the kernel first? How?

Yes you do. You do this by:

1. Downloading/compiling/installing the correct cross-compilation toolchain. For example, on Debian to get an ARM cross-compilation toolchain I can do `sudo apt install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi`, which will install all the binaries you normally have in `binutils` with the prefix `arm-linux-gnueabi-` (e.g. `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, `arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump`, etc...). You need all of the binutils, not only `gcc`.
2. Setting `ARCH=` to your desired target architecture, for example `ARCH=arm`.
3. Setting `CROSS_COMPILE=` to your cross-compilation toolchain prefix, for example `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-`. This also works if you want to use a downloaded toolchain as you can specify `CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/toolchain/` assuming this directory contains all the needed executables.
4. Getting a valid config for the target system. If you have a `.config` on the system you can use that one (simply copy it from the target system into `KDIR/.config`) and then update it with `make menuconfig`.
5. Building with `make all` or whatever other target you need.